# Authorize dataset to access another dataset

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery

What I have right now is I am authorizing using views. Now, I want to access all the underlying data inside a dataset.

```
view_dataset: '***'
view_table: '***'
table_dataset: '***'
    
view_string = "view={'projectId': '" + view_project + "', 'datasetId': '" + view_dataset + "', 'tableId': '" + view_table + "'}"
view_source = bigquery.Table(view_project + '.' + view_dataset + '.' + view_name)
    
dataset = client.get_dataset(table_project + '.' + table_dataset)
access_entries = dataset.access_entries

table_source = bigquery.Dataset(table_project + '.' + table_dataset)
access_entries.append(bigquery.AccessEntry(None, "view", view_source.reference.to_api_repr()))
table_source.access_entries = access_entries
table_source = client.update_dataset(table_source, ["access_entries"])
```

How will I be able to authorize `view_dataset` to access `table_dataset` programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

To anyone who wants to authorize programatically, here is how I did it:

Create an entity ID for the dataset:

```
entity_id = {
   'dataset': {
   'projectId': table_project,
   'datasetId': view_dataset,
   },
   'target_types': 'VIEWS'
}
```

Then, instead of `view`, use `dataset`:

```
access_entries.append(bigquery.AccessEntry(None, "dataset", entity_id))
```

I've managed to do this by reading the `AccessEntry` class on `dataset.py` of BigQuery.

```
If the ``entity_type`` is 'dataset', the ``entity_id`` is a ``dict``
that includes a 'dataset' field with a ``dict`` representing the dataset
and a 'target_types' field with a ``str`` value of the dataset's resource type:

{
     'dataset': {
     'projectId': string,
     'datasetId': string,
     },
     'target_types: 'VIEWS'
}
```